# exchanging an os.system() to driver.execute_script in python

Tags: python, android, appium, driver, os.system

I need to run this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys notification | egrep NotificationRecord | awk -F\| '{print $2}' >result.txt"
```

I used os.sestem('command') but I realise I should run this command like:

```
driver.execute_script('mobile: shell', {
'command': 'echo',
'args': ['arg1', 'arg2'],
'includeStderr': True,
'timeout': 5000
 })
```

I don't know how to exchange my command that runs correctly?
I used:

> driver.execute_script('mobile: shell', {'command': 'dumpsys','args':["notification","| egrep NotificationRecord | awk -F| '{print $2}' >result.txt"
> "]})

but didn't work!

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.run` ?

Comment: yes but I have several devices at the same time and I just want to run this command on one of them so I should use my driver.